# Using returning data with get request for Post reques

Tags: post, postman

So my question is , is it possible to do a post request and then you will get data from the server. And with that data you will do again a post request.

So for example, you will do this, post request:

```
{ "type": "success", "id": 5483 }
```

You wil get this data:

```
{
 "title" : "test title",
 "singer" : "some singer"
}
```

And with that data you will do again a post request, but then you will change the values, like this:

```
{
 "title" : "test title2",
 "singer" : "some singer2"
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done to find an answer to this?

Comment: Of course I googled. I found something like this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313715/rest-can-i-use-post-request-to-read-data but it is not totally the same

Comment: Yes Possible! Everything with Postman.

Comment: Oke, thak you all for the replies

Comment: I don't think i'm following, you make a request, read data, change data then make a new request? What's the point of having to read the data from the first request?

Comment: I have solved. Something that is hidden. Can't show it.